# C# compiler can't run on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I downloaded .Net Core from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd) installed it on Windows 10 x64, set path to C# compiler, Roslyn. When calling `csc` from command prompt I get a message;

```
This app can't run on your PC.
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.
```

I do not want to install Visual Studio and can't figure out the problem. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: It can. I'm using it right now. I bet most of the developers that use .NET Core are actually using Windows 10. What did you try? What was the full command line you used, including paths? Did you call the wrong version perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I even tried to call 'csc' from within the folder that the compiler is found and had the same message, so path is not the problem.

Comment: Does the `dotnet` command run?

Comment: @SLaks, yes it runs!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Runcsc` batch file found in same directory

Not sure why the `csc.exe` is not working directly but this works in my case